# loading from RWTexture2D<float4> in a compute shader

Tags: hlsl, directx-11, compute-shader

I understand there's a limitation in HLSL shader model 5.0 where one cannot load data from a non-scalar typed RWTexture2D resource.  That is to say, the following is illegal:

```
    RWTexture2D<float4> __color;
    float4 c = __color[PixelCoord];  // error here
```

So what exactly is the workaround?  I'm trying to accumulate into a float4 buffer in a compute shader, like so:

```
    c = computeColor( ... );
    __color[PixelCoord] += c;
```

Comment: There's different ways to work around this, but that depends on what you exactly need to do. You could use 2 textures and do ping pong (probably the easiest way if it applies to you), another way is to use StructuredBuffers, which haven't got this limitation, but are 1 dimension (it's not very hard to modify offsets from 2d to 1d tho).

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

float4 c = __color.Load( int3( UV, 0 ) );

Where UV is the xy coordinate in screen space (0 -> Resolution) of the texel you want to sample.

If you need to write to it, make sure it is bound from a UAV and not a shader resource view.