# Reading data from RWTexture2D in compute shader Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hlsl, texture2d, compute-shader

I'm learning compute shader with Unity, but I've encountered a bug when transferring RenderTexture to the compute shader. Basically, there're 2 texture being transferred, `renderTexture` and `copyTex`. The steps are as follow:

1. `copyTex` copy from `renderTexture` with `Graphics.CopyTexture()`
2. Both are transferred to compute shader, and a new `renderTexture` would be calculated from `copyTex`
3. Compute shader finished, `renderTexture` is used to display, then everything looped again

But for some reason, the `copyTex` after transferred to the compute shader is blank.

This is the main C# code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ComputeShaderTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ComputeShader computeShader;
    public RenderTexture renderTexture;
    private RenderTexture copyTex;

    [SerializeField] private Image image;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2Int size = new Vector2Int(512, 512);

    private Texture2D tex;

    void Start()
    {
        InitializeRenderTexture();
        StartCoroutine(SlowTest());
    }

    private void InitializeRenderTexture()
    {
        if (!renderTexture)
        {
            renderTexture = new RenderTexture(size.x, size.y, 24);
            renderTexture.enableRandomWrite = true;
            renderTexture.Create();

            copyTex = new RenderTexture(size.x, size.y, 24);
            copyTex.enableRandomWrite = true;
            copyTex.Create();
        }

        //populate texture2d with all white and black patch in middle
        Vector2Int pos = new Vector2Int(size.x / 2, size.y / 2);
        tex = new Texture2D(size.x, size.y, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        for (int i = 0; i < size.x; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size.y; j++)
            {
                tex.SetPixel(i, j, Color.white);
            }
        }
        for (int i = pos.x-10; i < pos.x+10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = pos.y-10; j < pos.y+10; j++)
            {
                tex.SetPixel(i, j, Color.black);
            }
        }
        tex.Apply();

        //copy to rendertexture
        RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
        Graphics.Blit(tex, renderTexture);
    }

    IEnumerator SlowTest()
    {
        UpdateTexture2D();
        while(true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            TouchTest();        
            Debug.Log("Passed");    
            UpdateTexture2D();
        }        
    }

    private void UpdateTexture2D()
    {
        RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;

        tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height), 0, 0);
        tex.Apply();
        image.material.mainTexture = tex;
    }

    private void TouchTest()
    {
        Vector2Int pos = new Vector2Int(size.x/2, size.y/2);
        Graphics.CopyTexture(renderTexture, copyTex);

        computeShader.SetInt("posX", pos.x);
        computeShader.SetInt("posY", pos.y);
        computeShader.SetInt("resolution", size.x);
        computeShader.SetTexture(0, "Result", renderTexture);
        computeShader.SetTexture(0, "Copy", copyTex);

        computeShader.Dispatch(0, renderTexture.width / 8, renderTexture.height / 8, 1);
    }
}
```

And the compute shader:

```
#pragma kernel CSMain

RWTexture2D<float4> Result;
RWTexture2D<float4> Copy;

int posX;
int posY;
int resolution;

int dx[9] = {-1, 1, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0};
int dy[9] = {1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0};

[numthreads(8,8,1)]
void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    int x = id.x, y = id.y;
    if (x != 0 && x != resolution - 1 && y != 0 && y != resolution - 1)
    {
        if (Copy[id.xy].a > 0.5) //white
        {
            Result[id.xy] = float4(1, 0, 0, 1); //set to red
        }
    }
}
```

I can conclude the `copyTex` is blank because right after copy, I tested it with this piece of code:

```
RenderTexture.active = copyTex;

tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, copyTex.width, copyTex.height), 0, 0);
tex.Apply();
image.material.mainTexture = tex;
```

and everything show up fine; but after the compute shader ran and the `renderTexture` got display, every pixels were red (which means the if statement activated, and all those pixels are previously white).

So texture can't be manipulated to transfer data and I have to use a custom `RWStructuredBuffer` instead or I mess up somewhere?

Update: Found out about `Load()` from this question: [loading from RWTexture2D<float4> in a compute shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588381/loading-from-rwtexture2dfloat4-in-a-compute-shader). Still can't get any type of info from `Copy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out that using `Load()` or `[]` operator isn't the problem, but the properties accessed. I used `Copy[id.xy].a`. Switched to `Copy[id.xy].x` and everything is fine.

These properties of `float4` is discussed here: [HSLS float1,..., float4 and its fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577239/hsls-float1-float4-and-its-fields). Basically, `.xyzw` is the equivalent of `.rgba` so accessing `a` actually access the alpha of the texture. As my alpha is always `1.0`, the result are always white.